# C++ Vector error

Tags: c++

i receive an error that the size of vector wasn't define. I cannot understand where I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int valoare;
    int vector[];

public:
    A(int param1=3):valoare(param1) {}
    int get_Valoare() {return this->valoare;}
};

int main()
{
    A vector[]=(*(new A(3)), *(new A(4)), *(new A(5)), *(new A(6)));
    cout<<vector[2].get_Valoare();
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't have a `std::vector`, you are trying to name an array `vector` (and that's definitely not how you initialize an array either)

Comment: `int vector[];` is not legal C++.

Comment: Also what is the point of `*(new A(3))`?? It seems you should start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Unless your type is specifically designed to accommodate it, `*new T` is almost certainly not the right thing to do.

Comment: `vector` is a **container class** and you are creating an array of name vector. This is not correct according to C++ standards. Read more about [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Your initialization is equivalent to `A vector[] = *(new A(6));` and a bunch of additional memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare a vector of the type `A`, which has a constructor that takes a single `int`, refer to the example below:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<A> my_vector{3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Comment: Note, that the constructor must not be marked `explicit`.